# Collapsible Text with fix height

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to do a collpasible text, that show like a "preview" of the text with a fix height of 248px. The with JS I remove this max-width and the user can see the full text.

The problem is in mobile I get the text cut in the middle depending on the size of the screen.

Can you help me to solve this issue?

Here is an example:

```css
.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 248px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsible-container enable-collapsible" data-aura-rendered-by="2478:0">
  <div class="collapsible-content" data-aura-rendered-by="2479:0">
    <p data-aura-rendered-by="2480:0">
      <div dir="ltr" data-aura-rendered-by="2483:0" class="uiOutputRichText" data-aura-class="uiOutputRichText">
        <p data-aura-rendered-by="2484:0">Do you want to make the shift to business leadership? As a general manager, do you need more confidence and influence so you can make a positive impact at a personal and business level?</p>
        <p data-aura-rendered-by="2484:0">Transition to Business Leadership (TBL) helps you make this move quickly and successfully through a unique combination of personal leadership development with coaching, strategy, execution and managing organizational change.</p>
        <p data-aura-rendered-by="2484:0">Completing TBL is your 2nd step to Program for Executive Development. You may also take TBL as a stand-alone program.</p>
        <!--render facet: 2484:0-->
      </div>
    </p>
  </div><button class="toggle-text toggle-text-more btn btn--text slds-button" data-aura-rendered-by="2485:0">+ Read more</button><button class="toggle-text toggle-text-less btn btn--text slds-button" data-aura-rendered-by="2487:0">- Read less</button></div>
```

Comment: Where is your JS? Please post that too..

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you toggling width or height?

Answer (score 0):

What type of control are you using to manage the state of the expanded content?

You can add a to the container that overrides the default style...

```
.collapsible-content.expanded {
  max-height: 100%;
}
<div class="collapsible-content expanded" data-aura-rendered-by="2479:0">
```

You'll need some JS to make that happen.